# MediaPlayer error when using NPR StreamProxy implementation

Tags: android, audio, stream

I'm trying to use NPR approach of streaming audio using the StreamProxy and PlaybackService class
The stream is an audio/aac file.

http://code.google.com/p/npr-android-app/source/browse/trunk/Npr/src/org/npr/android/news/PlaybackService.java

(The streamProxy.Java is in the same path as above, could not include two links in the post)

But am getting an error. The log I'm getting is

```
12-27 20:37:29.170 D/org.npr.android.news.PlaybackService(21817): downloading http://provisioning.streamtheworld.com/pls/KVKIFMAAC.pls
12-27 20:37:29.647 D/LocationMasfClient( 1089): getNetworkLocation(): Location not found in cache, making network request
12-27 20:37:30.436 D/LocationMasfClient( 1089): getNetworkLocation(): Number of prefetched entries 5
12-27 20:37:30.499 D/LocationMasfClient( 1089): getNetworkLocation(): Returning network location with accuracy 70.0
12-27 20:37:30.514 D/libgps  ( 1089): GpsInterface_inject_location( 12.969496, 77.632734, 70.000 )
12-27 20:37:30.866 I/BATTD   ( 1016): set_charge_current=0
12-27 20:37:30.866 I/BATTD   ( 1016): set_charge_voltage=3800
12-27 20:37:30.881 D/org.npr.android.news.PlaybackService(21817): listening to http://2173.live.streamtheworld.com:80/KVKIFMAACCMP3 stream=true
12-27 20:37:30.889 D/org.npr.android.news.PlaybackService(21817): SDK Version 8
12-27 20:37:30.889 D/org.npr.android.news.PlaybackService(21817): reset: http://2173.live.streamtheworld.com:80/KVKIFMAACCMP3
12-27 20:37:30.913 I/StagefrightPlayer( 1010): setDataSource('http://2173.live.streamtheworld.com:80/KVKIFMAACCMP3')
12-27 20:37:30.913 D/org.npr.android.news.PlaybackService(21817): Preparing: http://2173.live.streamtheworld.com:80/KVKIFMAACCMP3
12-27 20:37:31.100 D/org.npr.android.news.PlaybackService(21817): Waiting for prepare
12-27 20:37:31.108 D/org.npr.android.news.PlaybackService(21817): downloading http://provisioning.streamtheworld.com/pls/KVKIFMAAC.pls
12-27 20:37:31.725 D/org.npr.android.news.PlaybackService(21817): listening to http://2173.live.streamtheworld.com:80/KVKIFMAACCMP3 stream=true
12-27 20:37:31.725 D/org.npr.android.news.PlaybackService(21817): SDK Version 8
12-27 20:37:31.725 D/org.npr.android.news.PlaybackService(21817): reset: http://2173.live.streamtheworld.com:80/KVKIFMAACCMP3
12-27 20:37:31.725 I/AwesomePlayer( 1010): interrupting the connection process
12-27 20:37:31.834 I/AwesomePlayer( 1010): mConnectingDataSource->connect() returned -2147483648
12-27 20:37:31.834 E/MediaPlayer(21817): error (1, -2147483648)
```

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong here.

Regards,
Hari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to answer my own question..

AACP streams could not be played through the NPR Streamproxy approach. They do work fine for mp3 streams though.